# How to define data type from user input in C++?

Tags: c++, templates

I have HashMap class:

```
template<typename K, typename T>
class HashNode
{
 ...
};

template<typename K, typename T>
class HashMap
{
...
};
```

I want to get from a user data type for HashMap. For example:

User issues in command line: 'I S'

that means int for key and string for value

And as a result:

```
HashMap<int, string>*my_map = new HashMap<int, string>(capacity);
```

I tried to solve this problem with switch command and reinterpret_cast<> but it looked too verbose.

```
switch ((int)typename1)
{
    case('I'):
        switch((int)typename2)
        {
            case('I'):
                HashMap<int, int>*table1 = new HashMap<int, int>(20);
                return table1;
            case('D'):
                HashMap<int, double>*table2 = new HashMap<int, double>(20);
                return table2;
         ...
}
```

What alternative for it?

Thank you

Comment: I am thinking of something along the lines of typeid() operator in C++. Maybe you can create a class that takes user input as string, parses it and returns a std::pair of types for the resulting hashmap and you can use that std::pair first second members to create a new hashmap?

Comment: Maybe a factor could help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57472952/design-pattern-flexibility-issue-factory-method/57473708#57473708

Answer (score 1):

This is overengineering, but I'm up for a challenge today...

So, you want to return one of N hash map types, selected based on user input? `std::variant` is the right type for the job. `variant<A,B,C>` is a sum type that can contain one of types `A`, `B`, or `C`. It was added to C++17 but you can find single-header implementations that work in C++11 like [this one](https://github.com/mpark/variant).

As you figured out, templates are the best way to generate boilerplate. You seem to want to pick a hash map value type based on the character, so let's give ourselves a way to define a mapping in a template:

```cpp
template <char C, typename TValue>
struct Opt { };
```

Then our goal is to generate your switch by listing a bunch of these options and passing the user input:

```cpp
auto table = CreateHashMap<Opt<'i', int>, Opt<'d', double>, /*etc*/>(user_input);
```

Where table is

```cpp
std::variant<std::monostate, HashMap<int, int>, HashMap<int, double>, /*etc*/>
```

(The first option, `std::monostate`, is a "empty" option for if the function fails)

And the generated code is:

```cpp
std::variant<std::monostate, HashMap<int, int>, HashMap<int, double>/*, etc */> CreateHashMap(char user_input) {
    switch (user_input) {
        case 'i':
            return HashMap<int, int>(60);
        case 'd':
            return HashMap<int, double>(60);
        /* case 'e': return etc; */
        default:
            return std::monostate{};
    }
}
```

### Step 1 - Deduce The Variant Type From A List Of Opts

This can be done by starting with `std::variant<std::monostate>`, and then recursively appending types one by one:

```cpp
template <typename... TOpts>
struct OptToVariantImpl;

// Recursive case - pass TValue to the variant
template <typename... TValues, char Code, typename TValue, typename... TOpts>
struct OptToVariantImpl<std::variant<TValues...>, Opt<Code, TValue>, TOpts...> 
    : OptToVariantImpl<std::variant<TValues..., HashMap<int, TValue>>, TOpts...> { };

// Terminal case - just expose the variant
template <typename TVariant>
struct OptToVariantImpl<TVariant> {
    using Type = TVariant;
};

// Initial variant just has an empty state.
template <typename... TOpts>
using OptToVariant = typename OptToVariantImpl<std::variant<std::monostate>, TOpts...>::Type;
```

### Step 2 - Generate the switch

Our "switch" for each option is easy because all options will produce the same result, the variant. You can chain them together in one big recursive ternary:

```cpp
return user_input == 'Code' ? return /*HashMapForThisOpt*/ : /*Pass the buck*/;
```

A smart O3 compiler should be able to inline that and be left with a switch block.

The filled-out code is:

```cpp
template <typename... TValues>
struct CreateHashMapImpl;

// Recursive case - Test code and return hashcode or evaluate next option
template <typename TVariant, char Code, typename TValue, typename... TOpts>
struct CreateHashMapImpl<TVariant, Opt<Code, TValue>, TOpts...> 
    : CreateHashMapImpl<TVariant, TOpts...> {
    constexpr TVariant operator()(char code) {
        return code == Code ? TVariant { HashMap<int, TValue>(60) } : CreateHashMapImpl<TVariant, TOpts...>::operator()(code);
    };
};

// Terminal case - return std::monostate for failure result.
template <typename TVariant>
struct CreateHashMapImpl<TVariant> {
    constexpr TVariant operator()(char code) { return TVariant { std::monostate{} }; }
} ;

template <typename... TOpts>
OptToVariant<TOpts...> CreateHashMap(char code) {
    return CreateHashMapImpl<OptToVariant<TOpts...>, TOpts...>{}(code);
}
```

### Step 3 - Use

```cpp
auto table = CreateHashMap<Opt<'i', int>, Opt<'d', double>, Opt<'c', char>>(user_input);
if (auto* result = std::get_if<HashMap<int, double>>(&table)) {
    std::cout << "double: " << result->find(42)->second;
}
```

Putting it all together:
https://godbolt.org/z/VBnMq2

You can see the example optimizes down to a simple switch.