# Array that hold casting declarations of structs

Tags: c++

I am trying to generalize the send receive process in the code.

By creating a table holding the response for each command.

I get a buffer of specific size for each response and I want to cast it using that table.

Problem is that my `struct Commmands` uses `void*` and I cannot cast using it.

```
struct Commands
{
  U16 opcode;
  void*    rparam;
  int rlen;
};
```

My question is it possible to hold an array of pointers in some way similar to this  :

```
 Commands arr[] = { { OPCODE1, (Response1*) Rsp, sizeof(Response1) }, 
                    { OPCODE2, (Response2*) Rsp, sizeof(Response2) }, 
                  }
```

But, that will allow me to cast the buffer later:

uint8_t buffer[MAX_RESP_SIZE];

```
arr[0] = buffer;
uint8_t respResult = arr[0]->RespStatus; // use it later.
```

Any elegant way to achieve this ?

Response1 and Response2 being different response structs (to different commands I am sending)

Edit: I don't want to use another switch case function for the casting as it makes the table redundant.

Comment: You should be able to cast to and from `void *`. Can you add an example that shows where you cannot?

Comment: The correct design pattern for your needs is: Abstract Factory. You can continue writing switch statements, but thats normally not the way to go. May be check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57472952/design-pattern-flexibility-issue-factory-method/57473708#57473708

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can cast your `void*` pointers into its original type like this:

```
if (arr[0].opcode == OPCODE1)
{
   Response1* buff = static_cast<Response1*>(arr[0].rparam);

   // use buff here
}
else if (arr[0].opcode == OPCODE2)
{
   Response2* buff = static_cast<Response2*>(arr[0].rparam);

   // use buff here
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am trying to avoid another function, I am trying to make the table do the switch-case .

Comment: @schantischul What do you mean by `to avoid another function`? I think your Q is a little bit vague and you should should revise it.