# Parse a string class name to create a shared pointer in c++

Tags: c++, string, initialization, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I have something like this

```
class myclass
{};


int main()
{
    std::string mystring("myclass");
    return 0;
}
```

And I want to do something like `std::shared_ptr<mystring> mysharedptr;` that is equal to `std::shared_ptr<myclass> mysharedptr;`. Do you have an idea of how I should proceed?

I want to be able to do something like this because I have 8 classes and I should create a pointer depending of the name. In order to not have a huge structure with a lot of if/else if, I was wondering if there is a solution.

Comment: is this a typo? `myclass` vs `mystring` ? Do the different types inherit from a common base? Are you aware of the factory pattern?

Comment: No, you can wrap it up and make it more fancy/easier to use but essentially having your big if/else list is the only way to do it

Comment: No that is not a typo

`
template<typename T>
std::shared_ptr<Base> myCreate()
{
    return std::make_shared<T>();
}
static const std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<Base> (*)()> myMap
    {
        {"ClassA", &myCreate<ClassA>},
        {"ClassB", &myCreate<ClassB>}
    };
`

I had this idea but it required that the classes have the same constructor. And, even if, all my classes  inherit from a common base i wanted to know if there is a general answer

Comment: This is a typical problem, which will be addressed by the factory or abstract factory pattern. You need to read about that. Basically you would need to implement a map or unordered_map with the key beeing your class name string and a corresponding function pointer or std::function that will create the class. No need to use big if/else constructs. You will find a too advanced solution in my post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57472952/design-pattern-flexibility-issue-factory-method/57473708#57473708

Answer (score 0):

So to answer my question (this works) :

```
#include <map>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
  
class Base
{
public:
    using Ptr = std::shared_ptr<Base>;
};
  
class DerivedA : public Base
{
public:
    DerivedA() { std::cout << "DerivedA" << std::endl; }
};
  
class DerivedB : public Base
{
public:
    DerivedB() { std::cout << "DerivedB" << std::endl; }
};
  
template<typename T>
std::shared_ptr<Base> myCreate()
{
    return std::make_shared<T>();
}
  
int main()
{
    static const std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<Base> (*)()> myMap
    {
        {"DerivedA", &myCreate<DerivedA>},
        {"DerivedB", &myCreate<DerivedB>}
    };
 
    Base::Ptr first, second;
    first = myMap.find("DerivedA")->second();
    std::cout << first << std::endl;
    second = myMap.find("DerivedA")->second();
    std::cout << second << std::endl;
 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can nowadays write `template<std::derived_from<Base> T> std::shared_ptr<Base> myCreate()`. You don't want just any `T`; it has to be convertible to `Base`. Needs `#include <concepts>`.